# when using 'echo' in function, why does result appear on previous line?

Tags: php, function, return-value, echo

I wrote up a function that echoed out the id at the otherside of a linked table.

when I write in the page that's calling the function--

```
echo "<br/>getalbumartistfunction: ".get_albumartistid($thisalbum);
```

it returns the artist_id number on the line *above* where I have that function call.
So I went into the function and switched it from 'echo' to 'return' and it now appears right after the colons like I would expect (and is probably more along the lines of what I need).

So it works. But I am extremely confused why it would show the result on the previous line when the function is set to echo it.

Comment: because this function obviously gets called before whole string  gets assembled.

Comment: @Eineki you just need more knowledge.

Comment: Damon, imagine you have some money in your pocket and some in the wallet. To buy something, you need money from both. But every time you take the wallet, you are giving money directly to the salesman. So, *before* you collect money from both pocket and wallet, you already gave your money from wallet away. That's why one should **never** echo anything from the function, unless it's special output function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The echo in the get_albumartistid is executed immediately when the function is called while the echo "
..." assembles the string before echoing it - essentially buffering the entire thing before it echoes. Return instead of echo is the proper way to handle this since that would effectively replace the function call with the string returned. If you were to use echo you'd have to:

```
echo "<br/>getalbumartistfunction: ";
get_albumartistid($thisalbum);
```

Which effectively becomes:

```
echo "<br/>getalbumartistfunction: ";
echo "<The artist id>";
```

In your original example that order of execution makes it:

```
echo "<The artist id>";
echo "<br/>getalbumartistfunction: ";
```

Since all echoes happen immediately when it's called and PHP is not done buffering your outer echo statement.

Answer (score 1):

Since the argument for `echo` needs to be known before `echo` is be called, the function `get_albumartistid` is called before. And thus any statement inside the function is also called before the `echo`. That’s why an `echo` inside the function will output data before the  `echo` outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `get_albumartistid` function is evaluated before the whole echo is output, that is, the echo inside the `get_albumartistid` is executed before the `echo "<br/>getalbumartistfunction: "`.

Answer (score 1):

`echo` sends content directly to the output buffer. When you have the `echo` statement in the function, this is what happens:

1. PHP encounters the outer `echo` statement. It starts constructing the string to send to the output buffer. The first thing it sees is the string `"<br/>getalbumartistfunction: "`. The next thing, concatenated onto the previous string, is the call to the function `get_albumartistid()`. It needs to evaluate this function call to finish evaluating the concatenation, so...
2. PHP executes the function `get_albumartistid()`. That function contains an `echo` statement. The content of the `echo` statement is sent to the output buffer. The function returns `null`.
3. The function returned `null`, so PHP concatenates `null` onto the previous string (leaving it unchanged).
4. The string in the outer `echo` is now finished, and `echo` is ready to return. It sends the string to the output buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Expression vs. execution order.

Your `echo "string" . get()` leads to following execution flow:

- PHP combines the expression following echo. The echo cannot be executed yet.
- The first string in the concatenation is static.
- To get the second string, the function needs to be called. When the function does anything funny (make fart noises or print something out) it does so right away at this point.
- The two string parts are combined into a new temporary string.
- Only now can echo output everything.